# Doesn't work "npx create-react-app my-new-app --typescript"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Please help me. When I try to generate a project (creative-react-app), I get an error, you can look in the screenshot. The screen also shows the versions of node, npm and npx. I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Did you even read the message? Maybe you just shouldn't use a nightly build of `node`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall your **nightly Node version** and install the stable version of Node. In the error, it says that babel isn't compatible with your version of Node.

It also could be that you have an old version of React installed locally. So if the first fix doesn't work try 
`npm uninstall react`

Comment: You are right that the error is caused by an unsupported nightly version of `node`. But the  second proposed solution will not do anything. `npx create-react-app` will install a version of react itself in the project.

Comment: You're right, that's how it's supposed to be. But I recently had the problem that npx create-react-app did not work because I had an old version of React installed globally.

Comment: You maybe mean an old version of `create-react-app`? `create-react-app` doesn't use your globally installed `react` version at all.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! that's what I meant. I had an old version of create-react-app installed which caused the error when I tried to use npx create react app